# How to access values from event in Splunk

Tags: splunk

I want to access the values of the events that are coming after splunk search .

Data is coming in below format on the event

```
18/06/28 14:12:07 250  219561  711914   72864    0  784778 - 18-06-28 14:08:43
```

I want to get all the data hourly on the basis this time `14:12:07`

Please suggest how we can do this in Splunk

Comment: are you looking for the query to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, the query you are looking for is the one below:

```
* | timechart span=1h count
```

This query is also showing an event count, but you can aggregate them according to your needs, as well as refine the filter of the implicit `search` command (i.e. of the `*`)

Comment: But this is not listing all the fields value i want to list all fields values in a graph which all starts with c_ and i want to give some different name to then when we will show that in graph

Comment: this is tricky... you can use `... | fields c_* ` to only get the fields you want. you can use `...| rename c_field1 AS c_newfield1, c_field2 AS c_newfield2` to rename the fields so they show up with proper labels in the graph. Please explain a little more of what result are you exactly looking for?